# Get a count of a particular column, based on another column of the same table - Power BI

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-datasource

I have two tables. 
Table A and Table B.

The relationship from Table A to Table B is one to many.
One Table A record gives me several Table B records.

Table A contains my master data and Table B contains additional data.

Here is what the two tables look like:

Table A:

```
 _________________________________
| ... | Confirmation Number | ... |
|_____|___________________________|
| ... |       7413080       | ... |
|     |                     |     |
```

Table B:

```
 ______________________________________________________________
| Confirmation Number | Occurrences | Name  |      Status      |
|_____________________|_____________|_______|__________________|
|       7413080       |      1      | DAVE  |  Not Clocked Off |
|_____________________|_____________|_______|__________________|
|       7413080       |      2      | STEVE |       Fine       |
|_____________________|_____________|_______|__________________|
|         ...         |     ...     |  ...  |        ...       |
```

The data I wish to display in my Power BI report is: 
1) The total amount of people (unique count on `Name`) - which I have achieved without issue
2) Based on the total amount of people, the number of `Fine` records
3) Based on the total amount of people, the number of `Not Clocked On` records

On my main screen, users can filter the data (Table A records) - which gives me the relevant number of records for Table B.

On Table B, for #1, I am doing a count of distinct records on the `Name` column:
[image]

Which gives me the desired result (bottom left):
[image]

To achieve #2 and #3, I created the same `Card` with a count of `Status`.
[image]

`78` is the number (count) of 'statuses' I have in Table B - that's fine I thought, I just needed to filter those results to show me how many records there are of `Not Clocked Off`...

So I created a `New Quick Measure` on the `Status` column, for a filter of `Not Clocked Off`.

[image]

Which gives me `29` records - that's 29 rows in Table B which have the status of `Not Clocked Off`. But this is meaningless to my users, I wish to have the total amount of **people** with the status of `Not Clocked Off`. Which means getting the distinct count of `Name` for the filter of `Not Clocked Off`.

How can I achieve this?

Doing a distinct count of `Status` gives me 2 (which is again, useless because of course there are 2 status types - `Fine` and `Not Clocked Off`).

Here is my relationship link:
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll want to write the measure yourself (instead of a quick measure) so you can get exactly what you want.

Try this:

```
CountNotClockedOff =
CALCULATE (
    DISTINCTCOUNT ( TableB[Name] ),
    FILTER ( TableB, TableB[Status] = "Not Clocked Off" )
)
```

For `CountFine` just change `"Not Clocked Off"` to `"Fine"` in the above.

Answer (score -3):

Use a relationship. Go to datasets and define relation ship. Make sure the table you group by filters the other table.

then Drop what ever you grop on in Table one 
then drop what u need to count in table 2. You can create a measure with distinct count rows

Comment: I'm not sure you read the OP, `The relationship from Table A to Table B is one to many.`